# Using analog clock to toggle the view of status bar

Tags: android, statusbar

How can I use an analog clock to toggle the view of status bar (click to show - reclick to hide)?

I'm currently using this code:

```
public void Display(View view){

   if(visibility !=0){
   AnalogClock analogclock=(AnalogClock)findViewById(R.id.analogClock1);
   analogclock.setOnClickListener(new AnalogClock.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AnalogClock analogclock=(AnalogClock)findViewById(R.id.analogClock1);
        analogclock.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);

        getActionBar().show();
        visibility=0;
    }

   });
   }

   else{
       AnalogClock analogclock=(AnalogClock)findViewById(R.id.analogClock1);
       analogclock.setOnClickListener(new AnalogClock.OnClickListener(){

        @Override   
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AnalogClock analogclock=(AnalogClock)findViewById(R.id.analogClock1);
            analogclock.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);

            getActionBar().hide();
            visibility++;
        }
```

It does hide the status bar, but does not show it when analog clock is clicked again.

Comment: if the clock is hidden, visibility = AnalogClock.gone and not 0

Comment: @wazaminator I'm not trying to hide the clock I'm trying to invoke a function so that when clock is clicked the status bar is in low profile mode. Thanks for your help!!!!